# How do I set an option as selected using Selenium WebDriver (selenium 2.0) client in ruby

Tags: ruby, select, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get familiar with the new ruby selenium-webdriver as it appears more intuitive mostly than the previous version of selenium and the ruby driver that went with it. Also, i had trouble getting the old selenium to work with ruby 1.9.1 in windows so I thought i'd look for an alternative. 
So far i've done this with my script:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "https://example.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'username')
element.send_keys "mwolfe"
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'password')
element.send_keys "mypass"
driver.find_element(:id, "sign-in-button").click
driver.find_element(:id,"menu-link-my_profile_professional_info").click
driver.find_element(:id,"add_education_btn").click
country_select = driver.find_element(:name, "address_country")
```

So basically I'm logging into my site and trying to add an education entry to my user profile.. I have a reference to a select box with options (in the country_select variable) and now i want to select an option with a given value.. I don't see how to do this in the new client.. The only thing I can think of doing is looping through all the options until I find the one I want, and then call execute_script:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#execute_script-class_method
method to set the selectedIndex.

Is there any other way to do this?
In the java api for selenium 2.0/webdriver here: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html
there is an example of doing this

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Edam");
```

It doesn't appear that the ruby version has this feature though unless I'm missing something.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please note that none of the above will work anymore. `Element#select` and `Element#toggle` have been deprecated. You need to do something like:

```
my_select.click
my_select.find_elements( :tag_name => "option" ).find do |option|
  option.text == value
end.click
```

Answer (score 35):

Full disclosure here: I have absolutely no working knowledge of Ruby.

However, I'm pretty good with Selenium so I think I can help. I think what you're looking for is the [`select`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#select-instance_method)  method. If ruby is anything like the other drivers you can use the select method to tell one of the options it is selected.

In pseudocode/java terms it would look something like this

```
    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.name("select"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for(WebElement option : options){
        if(option.getText().equals("Name you want")) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

The Select object you have above is actually in a special Support package. It only exists for Java and .Net at the moment (Jan 2011)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i tried

country_select = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//select[id='address_country']/option = 'Austria'")
country_select.select 

and that didn't do anything. I think the select method is like calling select() in javascript (puts focus in a field and highlights the text)

Comment: Did you try first getting the select element, then iterate through the WebElement options and call the select method on the WebElement you want?

Comment: pnewhook got it right. Here's the equivalent Ruby code:

https://gist.github.com/777516

If Element#select doesn't work, perhaps try Element#toggle. If you think the API is too low level, you may want to check out the watir-webdriver gem as an alternative API to the same technology.

Comment: Won't you need `option.getText().equals("Name you want")` instead of `option.getText()=="Name you want"` ?

Comment: option.setSelected(); is deprecated and removed from 2.2 or 2.3 version. Use option.click(); instead

Comment: [@janderssn in this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2#6435526) provided a good answer.

Comment: @Sloin: What if you want to select multiple? Each click will cancel the previous...

Answer (score 14):

I don't know what version Selenium this came about, but it looks like there is the Select class that pnewhook mentioned in Selenium 2.20

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn-history/r15117/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Support/Select.html

```
option = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:xpath => "//select"))
option.select_by(:text, "Edam")
```

Comment: This is the best answer! There's no need to iterate through elements on your own, not to mention having to look at :tag_name => 'option' over and over again in your code. Pro tip: for easy access to the Select class (i.e. Select.new instead of Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new), use: include Selenium::WebDriver::Support

Comment: If you want to select by value, you can do that too: `option.select_by(:value, "edam")`

Answer (score 7):

pnewhook got it but I'd like to post the ruby version here so everyone can see it:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
driver.get "https://example.com"  
country_select = driver.find_element(:id=> "address_country")
options = country_select.find_elements(:tag_name=>"option")
options.each do |el|
    if (el.attributes("value") == "USA") 
        el.click()
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **XPath** to avoid looping:

```
String nameYouWant = "Name you want";
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id(id));
WebElement option = 
  select.findElement(By.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'" + nameYouWant + "')]"));
option.click();
```

or

```
WebElement option = 
  select.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='" + nameYouWant + "']"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
webdriver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

driver.navigate.to url

dropdown = webdriver.find_element(:id,dropdownid)
return nil if dropdown.nil?
selected = dropdown.find_elements(:tag_name,"option").detect { |option| option.attribute('text').eql? value}
 if selected.nil? then
  puts "Can't find value in dropdown list"
 else
  selected.click
 end
```

In my case this is only one working sample.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version of Webdriver (RC3) you should use "click()" instead of setSelected(). Also option.getText().equals("Name you want") should be used instead of option.getText()=="Name you want" in JAVA:

```
<!-- language: lang-java --> 
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.name("select"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(WebElement option : options){
    if(option.getText().equals("Name you want"){
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Code with Example:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie

driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
a=driver.find_element(:link,'Advanced search')

a.click


a=driver.find_element(:name,'num')

options=a.find_elements(:tag_name=>"option")
options.each do |g|
  if g.text == "20 results"
  g.click
  break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#SELECT FROM DROPDOWN IN RUBY USING SELENIUM WEBDRIVER
#AUTHOR:AYAN  DATE:14 June 2012

require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"



  begin
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://www.yoururl.com"
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30

    @driver.get "http://www.yoursite.com"


    #select Urugway as Country
     Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "country")).select_by(:text, "Uruguay")

        rescue Exception => e
         puts e
         @driver.quit


    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found was:

```
select_elem.find_element(:css, "option[value='some_value']").click
```