# Selenium 2 and JUnit in eclipse how to work with dropdown list?

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

how to deal with dropdown list in Selenium 2 , Juint in eclipse? I am not able to convert my my selenium ide syntax to Junit for Dropdownlist. how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would be helpful?:
[How to select/get drop down option in Selenium 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2)

You just have to create new JUnit test, initialize selenium and reach dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

just use findElement by id or name and send the keys.. Give me the code snippet if you didn't follow this, I may help u out in a better way....