# How do you click a select option in IE with webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```java
private void select(WebDriver driver, String select_text) {
    System.out.println("Selecting "+select_text+" from drop down menu");
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("roomMenu")));
    select.selectByVisibleText(select_text);
}
```

This function works fine with firefox, but when running in IE, it doesn't click on any option. Is there a specific way I have to do it for IE?

EDIT:
I rewrote it without using the Select object and it still refuses to click the option.

```java
private void select(WebDriver driver, String select_text) {
    System.out.println("Selecting "+select_text+" from drop down menu");

    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.name("roomMenu"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    for (WebElement option : options) {
        if (option.getText().equals(select_text)) {
            System.out.println(option.getText());
            option.click();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out the correct option so I know it found the right one, but when I do option.click() nothing happens in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I use -

```
private boolean selectFromDropDown(String locator, String value) {
    try {
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator))).selectByVisibleText(value);
        return true;
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
            System.out.println("Could not find element");
            return false;
        }
}
```

Works fine in IE too!
Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2).