# Dropdown selection automation using selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I need to automate the selection for a drop down box in selenium. The html code which comprises the dropdown is given below. The html code for each component is taken using firebug.

```html
// Input Area

<input type="text" title="Filter by Administrator" readonly="readonly" value="Filter by   Administrator" id="dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input" class="rcbInput   rcbEmptyMessage" name="dnn$ctr373$View$BusinessList_admin_dd" autocomplete="off">

// Dropdown arrow

<a style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;"   id="dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Arrow">select</a>

// Values inside drop down

<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
<li class="rcbItem ">All</li>
<li class="rcbItem ">dat@nykkos.com</li>
<li class="rcbHovered ">dat1@nykkos.com</li>
</ul>
```

I use the following code for automating the dropdown selection, based on the reply from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2).

```java
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input\"]")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("All");
```

The code gives me the following exception:

```java
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been  "select" but was "input"
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.35-32-generic',  java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.<init>(Select.java:46)
at FilterByAdministrator.testFilterByAdministrator(FilterByAdministrator.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am not sure, whether the code I used above for dropdown selection is correct or not.

Can someone please let me know the possible solution for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='select']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='All']")).click();
```

It might work. As per your html it's not looking like a select box. You may achieve it with normal click operations.

Comment: Above lines with case sensitive touchup 
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='select']")).Click();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='All']")).Click();

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input"));
```

Instead of:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input\"]")));
```

**EDIT**

Try the below code and let me know if it is working.

```
WebElement DropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input"));

Dropdown.sendKeys("All");
```

Comment: Check the EDIT in my answer and let me know if you are still facing the same issue.

Comment: maybe `Dropdown.click` will work better. And then you will have to find the elements shown in the dropdown.

Comment: seems it works ok now.. I will post my comment further after a detailed check  and accept the answer.  thanks for the help.

Comment: with the given code, though the exception is gone, it just highlights the "All" element in the drop down. A click on the drop down item is not happening. Also, though I change "All" to "dat@nykkos.com" which is the second value in the drop down, it still keep showing "All" as highlighted as shown by the image in the post.

Comment: Add `Dropdown.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` after `Dropdown.sendKeys("All");`

Comment: basically Dropdown.sendKeys is not working as I mentioned above, since instead of "All" no matter what other value I provide as input , it is not getting selected/highlighted

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message it says -

```
Element should have been  "select" but was "input"
```

Which indicates that the web element in question is an input field type.
So instead of selecting, try typing/`send` your input, like so

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr373_View_BusinessList_admin_dd_Input")).sendKeys("All");
```

Comment: this does not work either. The same issue I get as mentioned in the comment above for  HemChe's answer

Answer (score 1):

In python webdriver dropdown selection is very easiest way. See the below code.

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")).select_by_visible_text(" enter text with you want select")
```

It should be work in python selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

Above lines with case sensitive touchup

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='select']")).Click();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='All']")).Click();
```