# Selenium WebDriver (2.0) - Multi-Selection [checkbox] Dropdown menu -

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is a link to a picture of the dropdown: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQs4Z.png

I have been researching this for a bit, but have been unable to find a suitable solution. The dropdown has a list of checkboxes that can be checked. Multiple selections are possible. Below is the HTML for the dropdown, which includes a "required field" asterisk and the Title of the dropdown. Sorry about the formatting is it comes out funky.

I believe it would be easier if it were a Select element, but being as it is an Input, I wanted to reach out and see the best way of handling such elements. I should mention, I am using WebDriver for MS Visual Studio 2010 C#.

Additionally, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900428/dropdown-selection-automation-using-selenium) which, while related, does not seem to be working with the checkboxes dropdown.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="background-color:White;">
        <span id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_lblRequired" class="RequiredIndicator">*</span>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="background-color:White;">2</td>
    <td valign="top" style="background-color:White;">Question 2 Cities?</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="border-color:White;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl00$gvQuestions$ctl03$hdnQId" id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_hdnQId" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl00$gvQuestions$ctl03$hdnVId" id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_hdnVId" value="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl00$gvQuestions$ctl03$hdnAId" id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_hdnAId" value="3">
        <div id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_Classic" style="width:150px;white-space:normal;">
            <table summary="combobox" border="0" style="border-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 150px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
                            <input name="ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl00$gvQuestions$ctl03$cblListItems2" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_Input" value="" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td class="rcbArrowCell rcbArrowCellRight">
                            <a id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_Arrow" style="overflow: hidden;display: block;position: relative;outline: none;">select</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="rcbSlide" style="z-index:6000;">
                <div id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Classic " style="display:none;">
                    <div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="width:100%;">
                        <ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
                            <li class="rcbItem"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Denver</label></li>
                            <li class="rcbItem"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">Los Angeles</label></li>
                            <li class="rcbItem"><label><input type="checkbox" class="rcbCheckBox">New York City</label></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input id="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_ClientState" 
    name="ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_ClientState" 
    type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value={"logEntries":[],"value":"292","text":"","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: From the image, it looks like it's working. Are any exceptions being raised?

Comment: The question was how to handle this menu with Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I handled this list drop down. Modeled after @CreativeManix 's logic.

```
IWebElement ddl = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_Tabbed_ContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl00_gvQuestions_ctl03_cblListItems2_Arrow"));
ddl.Click();
IList<IWebElement> lis = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("rcbItem"));
foreach (IWebElement li in lis)
    try
    {
        IWebElement checkBox = li.FindElement(By.ClassName("rcbCheckBox"));
        //if (checkBox.Selected)
        checkBox.Click();
        break;
    }
    catch {}
```

Comment: For those reading the code, it checks all boxes in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic html. Though it looks like drop down, it is not. It is just list of check boxes.

If you want to Check the CheckBox based on City, do as follow

```
1) select all elements by class name "rcbItem" which is LI
2) now Iterate each element, and Read "Text" property
3) if the Text property is equals to your target city (which needs to be selected)
4) Select child element by class name "rcbCheckBox" using current element (i.e. LI)
5) and set the value attribute
```

I don't have Selenium setup now to write code for you... but the this logic should work

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on some code and will check your answer as best when it works!!

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Probably doing it wrong. Anyone have a code translation of the above logic?