# Getting the Value which is already selected in drop down menu by Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a Drop Down menu which has pre-selected a value please help me how to get the selected value text and print it in console

drop down menu html code is

```
<select id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCalculation" class="normalText" 
    style="width:100%;"
    onchange="javascript:LoadMethods(this.value);
              CallonChange(this.value,'spn_ddlCalculation');
              return false;"
    disabled="disabled" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCalculation">

    <option value="0" selected="selected">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="f">Formula Based</option>
    <option value="m">Formula Based with Matrix Table</option>
    <option value="q">Quantity Based</option>
    <option value="t">Time Based</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select/get drop down option in Selenium 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following and let me know if it works :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement("Use the correct selector");
WebElement option = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
String content = option.getText();
System.out.println("selected Value " + content);
```

Comment: Works fine i have added few more lines it might help u