# How to change a value of an object (Element in an HTML Code) through Selenium?

Tags: python, object, selenium

Here's my code:

```
import threading
import Queue
import socket
import pickle
import base64
import time

def enter_mashov():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

    # Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    start = time.time()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get('https://safe.mashov.info/students/login.aspx')

    # find the elements
    IDChanger = driver.find_element_by_id('TextBoxId')
    PassChanger = driver.find_element_by_id('TextBoxPass')

    IDChanger.send_keys('someid')
    PassChanger.send_keys('somepass')

enter_mashov()
```

I'd like to do the same as I did with the ID Changer and the Password Changer, but I the problem is, it's a drop-down list, and it's options doesn't own IDs or names, but a value.
How to change an object's value, then?
Let's say, change it's value and by that, PICKING an option from the options of the drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with a `<select>` element use the `Select()` class.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select_id"))
select.select_by_visible_text("The thing you want to select")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [iterate through the elements](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms) by tag name and select an option that way, or you could use their [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), which does not require the elements to have an id:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")
allOptions = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in allOptions:
    print "Value is: " + option.get_attribute("value")
    option.click()
```

There's a very similar question about [how to do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2).

[xpath method](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath) in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
inputs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input")
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown list is most likely a `select` element.

Inside the `select` element will be a group of `option` elements.

```
<select...>
    <option value="valueForFirstOption"...>Visible text for first option</option>
    <option value="valueForSecondOption"...>Visible text for second option</option>
</select>
```

Use the web developer tools in your browser to see the html code for your dropdown list and check this is the case.

To set its value, just do what a user would do:

1. Click on the `select` element
2. Click on the `option` element you want to pick.

There are multiple ways to locate the option element.
If you want to identify it by the visible text, use @MarkRowlands answer.
If you want to locate it by its value, you can use a css selector such as `option[value='valueToPick']`.