# Selenium webdriver Select

Tags: java, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello im trying to select Canada with selenium webdriver(on jav) with mozilla

my code is :

```
 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("address.country")));
select.selectByValue("CA");
```

it not working can someone please help me

```html
<select id="address.country" name="countryIso" class="dd dd"><option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a country</option>
     <option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="US">United States</option></select></div>
```

Comment: There might be a java event watching it. Try `driver.findElement(By.id("address.country")).click()` after your `selectByValue`.

Comment: Already try that it not working i been trying really hard to find a way still got nothing that worked

Comment: Then I guess you will just have to resort to Google. How about one of these 7 answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6430462/3124333

Answer (score 1):

For detailed explanation of how to select a value in different ways, please watch the below video:
[How to select a value from listbox in different ways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfYj3DYnN0c)

And I tried below code, and both of them are worked fine.

Here is your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="address.country" name="countryIso" class="dd dd">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a country</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="US">United States</option></select></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Selenium code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("file:///D:/Programming%20Samples/Temp.html");
        WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.id("address.country"));
        Select sel=new Select(ele);
//      sel.selectByVisibleText("Canada");
        sel.selectByValue("CA");
```

If you still see some problem, get latest version of Selenium and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code

```
WebElement country = driver.findElement(By.id("address.country"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(country).perform();
new Select(country)
                .selectByVisibleText("Canada");
```

or

```
Select countryValue = new Select(
                    country);
            countryValue.selectByValue("CA");
```

Comment: Dint work :( both of them