# How to identify the webelements(button,drop down etc) by using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

How to identify webelement buttons by selenium webdriver
executeScript method is undefined. Where to add this
`driver.executeScript("return $('body /deep/ <#selector>')")` ?

Comment: Try this`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`. You will have to change the locators accordingly in your automation code.

Comment: ya i tried this. It works for button , but for dropdown how to use this element.            I want to print dropdown list in console                                                                    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("countTd"));
    dropDown.click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='countTd']/span[text()='"']")).click.getOptions();

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2

Comment: @arpitasoni You don't have to use JavascriptExecutor for this. Also, you don't have to click the element as well. Try this code `Select selectElement = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("countTd"))); List<WebElement> options = selectElement.getOptions();`. You can iterate through the options list and print the values using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for retrieving all dropdown values

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 10);
    WebElement selectMonth = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title = 'Birthday']")));
    selectMonth.click();
    List<WebElement> allmonths = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("span#BirthMonth > div.goog-menu.goog-menu-vertical")));
    for(WebElement month : allmonths) {
                System.out.println(month.getText());
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

We will get this type of Exception in below scenario.

1. If pages are not embedded in `jQuery`.
2. `jQuery` library is not loaded successfully.
3. Browser syn isssue.

First check pages is embedded in `jQuery` or not by executing below command on browser console

```
window.jQuery=='undefine' // Its for checking jQuery is present on page if yes then return true.
```

and

```
jQuery.active==0  // Its for  checking jquery is activated on page if yes then return true.
```

then try below code

```
String getArgument="0"; // take single element
//String getArgument="";// take list of matched element

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return $( #selector).get(" + getArgument + ");");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply identify element by using `getTagName()` as below :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("countTd"));

// To verify if element is button
if(element.getTagName().equals("button")) {
   element.click();
}

// To verify if element is dropdown
if(element.getTagName().equals("select")) {

  // Now pass it to Select class to work 
  Select selectElement = new Select(element); 

  // Now you can get all options
  List<WebElement> options = selectElement.getOptions();

  //Now you can print all options text
  for(WebElement option : options) {
      System.out.println(option.getText());
  }
}
```

**Node** :- There is no need to use `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click, it would be simply perform by calling `.click()` method.

Hope it helps..:)