# Select value from drop-down - Python Webbot

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-deploy, webbot

> Hi All, I'm tring to select a value from drop-down list but its not working.

This is the dropdown that Im trying to select

[image: This is the dropdown that Im trying to select]

> Below is my script.

'''

```
from webbot import Browser
import time

web = Browser()
web.go_to('https://*****.service-now.com/')
web.type('*****\t')
web.type('*****\t\t')
web.type(web.Key.ENTER)
web.maximize_window()
web.click('Incident', tag='span')
time.sleep(25)
web.click('Open - Unassigned', tag='div')
time.sleep(5)
web.click('Short description', value='short_description')
```

'''

> Below is copied element of drop-down
>
> copy element:

```
<select id="c7f1a59007dc1410af12f2ae7c1ed03d_select" class="form-control default-focus-outline"> 
<option value="zztextsearchyy" selected="SELECTED" role="option">for text</option><option 
value="number" role="option">Number</option><option value="opened_at" role="option">Opened</option> 
<option value="short_description" role="option">Short description</option><option value="caller_id" 
role="option">Caller</option><option value="priority" role="option">Priority</option><option 
value="state" role="option">State</option><option value="category" role="option">Category</option> 
<option value="assignment_group" role="option">Assignment group</option><option value="assigned_to" 
role="option">Assigned to</option><option value="sys_updated_on" role="option">Updated</option> 
<option value="sys_updated_by" role="option">Updated by</option></select>
```

> Xpath: (If needed)

```
//*[@id="c7f1a59007dc1410af12f2ae7c1ed03d_select"]
```

> When tried to run the code gave me below error.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64454/devtools/browser/570915fb-92df-4ce0-97ed-6d20c8efd860
[5772:10264:0417/003932.575:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "WebAut.py", line 14, in <module>
web.click('Short description', value='short_description')
TypeError: click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'
```

PLEASE Assist on this

Comment: May this help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430462/how-to-select-get-drop-down-option-in-selenium-2) or this [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38194/selenium-python-drop-down-menu-select)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='c7f1a59007dc1410af12f2ae7c1ed03d_select']/option[text()='Short description']").click()
```

Comment: Hi @Dipak bachhav thanks for the suggestion.

Im not using selenium. Im using Webbot along with python so this would not work. Any other suggestion on this. And sorry I forgot to mention that ID for drop-down keeps changing. I tried using classname too but it didn'nt worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question.  For Webbot specifically, this is what worked for me:

```
web.click(xpath="//select[@id='c7f1a59007dc1410af12f2ae7c1ed03d_select']/option[text()='Short description']")
```