# How to select an item from a dropdown list using Selenium WebDriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can I select an item from a drop down list like gender (eg male, female) using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

I have tried this

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("gender"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("Male"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if("Germany".equals(option.getText()))
        option.click();   
}
```

My above code didn't work.

Comment: Similar to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232544/selenium-webdriver-and-dropdown-boxes

Comment: sorry this couldn,t help me out.. can you provide me the way or give me any idea so i can proceed

Comment: Stackoverflow users helps those who help themselves :)

Comment: I wonder if you don't convert a select WebElement to Select, then could it be possible that selenium will click the wrong option ? See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031592/python-selenium-webdriver-select-option-does-not-work

Answer (score 44):

Use -

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gender"))).selectByVisibleText("Germany");
```

Of course, you need to  `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;`

Comment: Note that in C# the class is `SelectElement` instead of `Select`. Also it's not part of the core `Selenium.WebDriver` package, to use this class you also have to install the `Selenium.Support` package.

Comment: Can you please tell us why we need to convert WebElement into a Select instance ? Is it only so that we can get Select specific methods which make it easy to automate select ? Also, can we automate a select, without using Select class ?

Answer (score 23):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));
```

Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
```

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

or

```
dropdown.selectByValue("prog");
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 5):

Tagname you should mentioned like that "option", if text with space we can use this method it should work.

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("gender"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

for (WebElement option : options) {

if("Germany".equals(option.getText().trim()))

 option.click();   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Google "select item selenium webdriver" brings up [How do I set an option as selected using Selenium WebDriver (selenium 2.0) client in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672658/how-do-i-set-a-an-option-as-selected-using-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-0-cli) as first result. This is not Java, but you should be able to translate it without too much work. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver is in the top 5, again not Java but the API is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

```
WebElement selectgender = driver.findElement(By.id("gender"));
selectgender.sendKeys("Male");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'Select' class of selenium WebDriver as posted by Maitreya. Sorry, but I'm a bit confused about, for selecting gender from drop down why to compare string with "Germany". Here is the code snippet,

```
Select gender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gender")));
gender.selectByVisibleText("Male/Female");
```

Import `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;` after adding the above code.
Now gender will be selected which ever you gave ( Male/Female).

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("gender"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
   if("Germany".equals(option.getText()))
       option.click();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a particular dropdown box element:

```
Select gender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gender")));
```

To get the list of all the elements contained in the dropdown box:

```
for(int j=1;j<3;j++)
    System.out.println(gender.getOptions().get(j).getText());
```

To select it through visible text displayed when you click on it:

```
gender.selectByVisibleText("Male");
```

To select it by index (starting at 0):

```
gender.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class checkBoxSel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         EventFiringWebDriver dr = null ;


         dr = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
         dr.get("http://www.google.co.in/");

         dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         dr.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click() ;

         Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
         sel.selectByValue("fil");

    }

}
```

I am using GOOGLE LOGIN PAGE to test the seletion option. The above example was to find and select language "Filipino" from the drop down list. I am sure this will solve the problem.