# check which item is selected from a list using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors

I have a `select` html item.

```
<select name="badge" data-validate="true"><option value="">none</option><option value="usd">USD</option>
<option value="eur">EURO</option>
<option value="ils">GBP</option></select>
```

I want to use selenium webdriver to

(1) select a item `EURO` from the list

(2) check `EURO` from the list is selected

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Select](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class. A C# equivalency example is as follows. Should not be too hard to

```
// select the first operator using "select by value"
IWebElement element = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("badge"));
SelectElement selectByValue = new SelectElement(element);
selectByValue.SelectByValue("EURO");

if (selectByValue.SelectedOption.Text.Contains("EURO "))
{
  //pass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First part appears to be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435526/4500832

For part 2 of your question you should be able to check what value the Select contains and verify that it's EURO.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IconImageTag getSelectedIconImageTag() {
    Select select = getIconImageTagsDropDown();
    WebElement selected = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
    return IconImageTag.valueOf(selected.getText());
}

private Select getIconImageTagsDropDown() {
    By dropDownSelector = By.cssSelector("#display_body > div.form-group.image_uploader.offer_logo > label > " +
            "select");
    WebElement tagsDropDown = driver.findElement(dropDownSelector);
    return new Select(tagsDropDown);
}


public void setSelectedIconImageTag(IconImageTag iconImageTag) {
    Select select = getIconImageTagsDropDown();
    select.selectByVisibleText(iconImageTag.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer in this post helps you: [How to select an item from a dropdown list using Selenium WebDriver with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940592/how-to-select-an-item-from-a-dropdown-list-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

The answer there is (I modified it slightly to your situation):

```
new Select(Driver.findElement(By.Name("badge"))).selectByVisibleText("EURO");
```

`